# Upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 and screen brightness can not be decreased

Tags: screen, brightness

The brightness remains maximum always. I am using ACER Aspire E1-572, and its brightness cannot be changed. I tried:

```
echo -n 100 > /proc/acpi/video/DVGA/LCD/brightness
echo -n 100 > /proc/acpi/video/DVGA/LCD/brightness
```

and results were:

```
bash: /proc/acpi/video/DVGA/LCD/brightness: No such file or directory
bash: /proc/acpi/video/VGA/LCD/brightness: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Look for the file `brightness` somewhere under `/sys` (the exact path depends on your hardware). The command is `find /sys | grep brightness`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find line that says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Replace `acpi_backlight=vendor` with `video.use_native_backlight=1`

If the former is not present, just add the latter.

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot. Let us know how it turns out.